# Background segmentation from multiple files.jpeg

Tags: matlab-figure

I am trying to  cut off background from  currency notes. I used a blobsDemo.m codes I found here, used on coins.jpeg. it worked we quite well for me, on one note.

But when I tried it on multiple images, it returns results on just one note:

```
For k=1:16
JpegFileName=sprintf('%d.jpeg',k);
    Fullfilename=fullfile('Folder',jpegfilename);
Imagedata=imread(Fullfilename)
    Originalimage=rgb2gray(imagedata);

Subplot(4,4,k)
Imshow(original image);%displays all my 16 distinct images.

 %but when I run 
 ThresholdValue(k)=100
   Binaryimage=originalimage>threshold.  value(k);
%it returns for one image.
End
```

What am I doing wrong please? I need help. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

for example if your resultant image is stored in variable "IM_out" then use IM_out(:,:,k)

Comment: Thanks Samuel. IM_out being my 'originalImage' you mean?    The 'originalImage' contain all 16 images converted to gray scale.  How do I use the thresholdvalue on 'originalImage'?

Comment: Binaryimage(:,:,k) = im2bw(originalImage,ThresholdValue);

Comment: Thank you again... I want to try it.

Comment: Error line 39 binaryimage(:,:,k)=(original image,ThresholdValue);

Comment: Binaryimage(:,:,k) = im2bw(originalImage,ThresholdValue);   copy this line and replace in your code line no 39

Comment: Please Samuel, maybe I should explain more explicitly so you can help me better. I have 16 images that I want to crop out from background (segmentation), using thresholding. What is the code to use from line one. Everything I had done never returns all images. Please. You may send me at ouche.Joseph @gmail.com